# Response time of an application unintutively correlated with number of input triggers in a give time period

Tags: c++, linux, multithreading, performance

I have an Multi threaded C++ network application which listens for UDP packets as input - this data then hops through the application/processed via various queues and threads and finally pushed out on a TCP socket.

What I am seeing is that if inputs come in slow lets say 5/sec, the total response time (in-to-out) is slow (lets say 100ms) and if the inputs come in fast e.g. 20/sec, the response time is also fast (~50ms). This observation is really weird. And also messes up the response time in the fast case because the 1st response is always slow. Just to make sure - the application is doing exactly the same amount of work in both slow and fast cases.

Things that have been tried to investigate this -

- Its a dual Xeon box running Linux 2.6 kernel - disabled Turbo boost, made sure processors are in C0 states.
- eliminated network causes. the root cause is within the box. ( in software or hardware )
- I have a fake input going through the system from input to output on a timer to keep the application "warm" - no effect. (the application
  's worker threads are busy waiting and pinned to cores).
- perf points indicate that EVERY thing gets slower - which basically mean that the processors are slowing down when not under continuous load - but nothing else suggests that ( 17z/turbostat) or I am reading them incorrectly.

Does someone has color on what might be happening?

Comment: Could it be buffering perhaps somewhere in the network loop?  The faster response causes the buffer to get dumped sooner, the slower messages take longer to fill up the buffers?

Comment: Can you eliminate TCP/UDP/IP entirely and just feed in "fake" packets to the front queues of your program and measure the latency to the end?

Comment: Are busy-waits truly busy? No waits, locks, mutexes, only spinlocks?

Comment: Do you perform memory intensive operation in standby? This could flush caches.

Answer (score -1):

In my experience, this would be the nasty doings of Nagle's devilish device. Sounds extremeliy plausible to me that more data in the buffer fills up TCP packet which than get's sent. Without much data, tcp packet is waiting for the ack from the other side, which is, as we all know, delayed.

Solution - learn to make sure Nagle's program killer is disabled the first thing after you create any send-capable TCP socket.